# How to use SQL one to many relation joins with sub-query

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created below query for report in SSRS 2008 R2 using matrix.

Please have a look at the below sample data and query.
=>Get the `inc_id` when the `usr_id` is reference into it in `incident` table.
=>In `actions` table, If any `inc_id` reference to another `usr_id` it will be skipped.
is there any changes need for the one to many relation in my query ? Please help

Table: **incident**

```
+--------+-------------+--------+---------+
| inc_id | date_logged | usr_id | dept_id |
+--------+-------------+--------+---------+
|    100 | 1-Aug-15    |      1 |      10 |
|    101 | 1-Sep-15    |      2 |      20 |
|    102 | 25-Aug-15   |      1 |      10 |
+--------+-------------+--------+---------+
```

Table:**Actions**

```
+--------+-----------+----------+--------------+--------+---------+
| inc_id | date_act  | act_type | servicr_time | usr_id | dept_id |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------------+--------+---------+
|    100 | 2-Aug-15  | Travel   |          300 |      1 |      10 |
|    100 | 3-Aug-15  | Remote   |          200 |      3 |      30 |
|    100 | 5-Aug-15  | Travel   |          200 |      1 |      10 |
|    100 | 10-Sep-15 | Travel   |          250 |      1 |      10 |
|    101 | 1-Sep-15  | Travel   |          150 |      2 |      20 |
|    101 | 1-Sep-16  | Travel   |          120 |      3 |      30 |
|    102 | 29-Aug-15 | Travel   |          150 |      1 |      10 |
|    102 | 30-Aug-15 | Remote   |          120 |      1 |      10 |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------------+--------+---------+
```

Query:

```
 SELECT COUNT(distinct inc.inc_id) AS [inc_count], 
         inc.inc_id,
       DATEPART(YEAR, a.date_act) 'act_year',
       DATENAME(MONTH, a.date_act) 'act_month',
       inc.dept_id, inc.usr_id,            
                 (
                    SELECT     ISNULL(SUM(ac.service_time), 0) AS Expr1
                    FROM          actions as ac
                    WHERE      (ac.act_type IN ('Travel Time')) 
                    AND (ac.inc_id = inc.inc_id) 
                    AND (DATEPART(YEAR, ac.date_act) = DATEPART(YEAR, a.date_act)) 
                    AND (DATENAME(MONTH, ac.date_act) = DATENAME(MONTH, a.date_act))
                    AND ac.date_act BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND DATEADD(day, 1, '2015-09-30')

                    ) / 60 AS [Travel_Time],

                (
                    SELECT     ISNULL(SUM(ac.service_time), 0) AS Expr1
                    FROM          actions as ac
                    WHERE      (ac.act_type IN ('Remote')) 
                    AND (ac.inc_id = inc.inc_id) 
                    AND (DATEPART(YEAR, ac.date_act) = DATEPART(YEAR, a.date_act)) 
                    AND (DATENAME(MONTH, ac.date_act) = DATENAME(MONTH, a.date_act))
                    AND ac.date_act BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND DATEADD(day, 1, '2015-09-30')

                    ) / 60 AS [Remote_Time]

FROM  incident AS inc 
    INNER JOIN inc_data as id ON inc.inc_id = id.inc_id 
    INNER JOIN actions as a ON a.inc_id = inc.inc_id       
WHERE a.dept_id IN (10)
  AND a.date_act BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND DATEADD(day, 1, '2015-09-30')
GROUP BY inc.inc_id,a.date_act,inc.dept_id, inc.usr_id
```

Result Expected (Sample):

```
+-----------+--------+------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+-------------+
| inc_count | inc_id | Year |   Month   | usr_id | dept_id | Travel_Time | Remote_Time |
+-----------+--------+------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|         1 |    100 | 2015 | August    |      1 |      10 |         500 |           0 |
|         1 |    100 | 2015 | September |      1 |      10 |         250 |           0 |
|         1 |    102 | 2015 | August    |      1 |      10 |         150 |         120 |
+-----------+--------+------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

logic : 
=> First check the inc_id in incident table reference to the usr_id 
=> Retrieve the data from actions table related to usr_id in incident table

Comment: What was the question ?

Comment: How i can modify my query to get the result like sample result as mentioned above .

Comment: I have reformated your query with proper indentation to better understand it. But there are mistakes in it: some parenthesis in the SELECT subqueries are not correct. Please fix this first

Comment: @ThomasG i have modified my query

Comment: logic : => First check the inc_id in incident table reference to the usr_id

=> Retrieve only the data from actions table related to usr_id in incident table